# Read and store data using vb script

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I have a file with following content

```
  aaaaaaaaa    filename1.txt
  bbbbbbbbbb   filename2.dat
```

i want to read this file and store data to the relevent file seperately.

eg :- aaaaa  ---> filename1.txt

Could someone please tell me the way to do this? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Sub Main

```
Set ctlpath = "\\Download_Directory\CA.ctl"
Set subDirectory = "AUB"
Set MkrExtention = ".mkr"

ReadCtl(ctlpath,subDirectory,MkrExtention )

End Sub

 Function ReadCtl(ctlFileName,ctlSubDirectory,MarkerFileExtension)

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim lineData,hashValue,fileName,fileToWrite

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(ctlFileName) Then

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ctlFileName, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

    lineData = objFile.ReadLine
    hashValue =Split(lineData,"  ") (0)
    fileName =Split(lineData,"  ") (1)

    WriteFileText("\\Download"+ctlSubDirectory+"
\"+fileName+MarkerFileExtension,hashValue)

Loop

objFile.Close
objFSO.Close

End If

ReadCtl = True

End Function

Function WriteFileText(sFilePath, sText)

Dim objFSO1 'As FileSystemObject
Dim objTextFile 'As Object

Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO1.CreateTextFile(sFilePath, True)

' Write hash data in to the file .mkr file
objTextFile.Write (sText)

objTextFile.Close
objFSO1.Close

 End Function
```

Comment: do you get errors ? is the result incorrect ? if so, publish them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time since you asked this, surprises me nobody answered, is simple enough.
Hope you'r still around, anyway here for reference. This is no real hash like eg in Ruby of course but i kept enough of your script so that you can compare.

```
ReadCtl("file2hash1.txt")

function ReadCtl(ctlFileName)
  const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, createIfNeeded = true
  set oFso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set oRegExpre = new RegExp
  oRegExpre.Global = true
  oRegExpre.Pattern = "(.*) +(.*)"
  if oFso.FileExists(ctlFileName) then
    set objFileRead  = oFso.OpenTextFile(ctlFileName, ForReading)
    do until objFileRead.AtEndOfStream
      lineData = objFileRead.ReadLine
      hashValue = oRegExpre.Replace(lineData,"$1")
      fileName  = oRegExpre.Replace(lineData,"$2")
      if oFso.fileExists(fileName) then
        modus = ForAppending
      else
        modus = ForWriting
      end if
      set objFileWrite = oFso.OpenTextFile(fileName, modus, createIfNeeded)
      objFileWrite.writeLine hashValue
      objFileWrite.close
    loop
    objFileRead.close
  end if
  set oFso = nothing
end function
```